# App crashes when I run the app. I dont know why?

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

my apps particular page crashes when i try to load it in my app.
Can someone find the mistake.
I will post the xml and java file of the code and also the error.

Java code:

```
    package com.divesh.sliderapp;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Team extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team,container,false);

        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.Name1);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Fonts/KoHo-Bold.ttf");
        txt.setTypeface(font);
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Fonts/KoHo-Regular.ttf");
        TextView txt1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Name2);
        TextView txt2 = view.findViewById(R.id.Pos1);
        TextView txt3 = view.findViewById(R.id.Pos2);
        txt1.setTypeface(font);
        txt2.setTypeface(font2);
        txt3.setTypeface(font2);
        TextView join = view.findViewById(R.id.join);
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
        join.setTypeface(font1);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Team");
    }
}
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2dede">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Name1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/divesh_jain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="115dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
        android:text="@string/divesh_jain"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Pos1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="115dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Pos1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        android:text="@string/developer"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="157dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="158dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Name2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/aman_jain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:text="@string/aman_jain"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Pos2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="132dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Pos2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="161dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:text="@string/designer"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/join"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="161dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/join"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:text="@string/wish_to_join_our_team_contact_us_via_query_section"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I will paste the errors show in logcat but none of them i think are for this page
This page name is team

here are the errors shown in logcat.

> 11-04 19:19:57.875 5921-5921/com.divesh.sliderapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.divesh.sliderapp, PID: 5921
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.divesh.sliderapp/com.divesh.sliderapp.payment}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
>           at com.divesh.sliderapp.payment.onCreate(payment.java:53)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
>           at com.divesh.sliderapp.payment.onCreate(payment.java:53) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.divesh.sliderapp:drawable/card10" (7f08005e)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f08005e a=-1 r=0x7f08005e}
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:146)
>           at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:86)
>           at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:82)
>           at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:78)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
>           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
>           at com.divesh.sliderapp.payment.onCreate(payment.java:53) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   11-04 19:20:00.461 5921-5921/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5921 SIG: 9

Comment: hmm... looks like it's related to your images. In your imageview, replace app:srcCompact with android:src for starters. Let me know how it behaves and I can look into it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error log:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   "com.divesh.sliderapp:drawable/card10" (7f08005e) is not a Drawable
>   (color or path)

this means that you try to use the drawable `card10` but this is not a drawable. 
Though the xml you posted does not use any drawable `card10`.

Also the error log points to line 64 of the xml where in the xml you posted I found `imageView8`. In this case maybe a very large picture has been set in this attribute and could crash the app:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/image5"
```

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: First remove `app:srcCompat="@drawable/image5"` and try again. If the app runs without a crash then you found the problem, it's the image. If it still crashes then look for this "drawable" `card10` and remove it too from your code and see what happens.

Comment: after removing the image, the error goes off. but how should i rectify the error as i want the image to be

Comment: Try with a liower resolution image.

Comment: yeah I got it. Solved the error. The actual issue was that i placed the image in v24. After changing the folder, everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is inflating at the time of replace your fragment with your container in your Activity

Comment: how can i set it proper?

Comment: Show me your fragment replacing code which you have done in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using View.findViewById() in onViewCreated :) all objects can be accessed by View like

View.findViewById(R.id.textview).setText(“hello world”);

Go though this:https://usman.sagri.co.in/pdaceapp/app/src/main/java/in/co/sagri/pdace/ContactFragment.java

You dint return view properly and move that code like in my java file.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView7.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2)
```

Try setting image programatically,this will solve the error